# How to get the field names situated in a ArrayType Column

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark

This is my Schema

```
    root
     |-- tags: array (nullable = true)
     |    |-- element: array (containsNull = true)
     |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
     |    |    |    |-- context: string (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |-- key: string (nullable = true)
```

I want to get the name of the elements context and key, and to change the datatype of those variables into an Array.

When I'm trying to get the fields using map, it is showing something like this.

```
arraydf.schema.fields.map(field1 =>
                println("FIELDS: "+field1)
Output: 
FIELDS:StructField(tags,ArrayType(ArrayType(StructType(StructField(context,StringType,true), StructField(key,StringType,true)),true),true),true)
```

I want my schema to be like this, the elements whichever will be under struct type should be of arrayType, I want a generic way. Please help me.

```
    root
     |-- tags: array (nullable = true)
     |    |-- element: array (containsNull = true)
     |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
     |    |    |    |-- context: array (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |-- key: array (nullable = true)
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of input/output DFs?

Comment: @pheeleeppoo I gave the schema example no? In my dataframe I'm taking a nested JSON file and flattening the schema just. and in the end I'm having this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pattern match over the structure

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame

def fields(df: DataFrame, c: String) = df.schema(c) match{
  case StructField(_, ArrayType(ArrayType(ss: StructType, _), _), _, _) => 
    ss.fields map { s =>
      (s.name, s.dataType)
    }
}
```

Example:

```
scala> fields(Seq(Seq(Seq((1, 2)))).toDF, "value")
res7: Array[(String, org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataType)] = Array((_1,IntegerType), (_2,IntegerType))
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I get, you just want to access to a element right? This is done via dot notation for StructType, and getItem for ArrayType (or just square brackets []).

So, if you want to have the values, let me say, try:

`arraydf.select("tags[0][0].context, tags[0][0].key")`

I suggest you to look at [explode()](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/sql/#explode) function as well, it could be useful.